# VBA Compare rows/columns in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on a VBA code that will allow me to see changes in trade positions day by day. I’m fairly new to VBA programming and would like to get some feedback on the code I have written (and copied from various posts here).

I have 3 sheets, one with today's trades (sheet1), one with yesterday's trades (sheet2) and one sheet that are supposed to highlight changes from "day n" to "day n-1" (sheet3). In column "A" I have trade ID that are unique for each trade (ID1, ID2 etc.), from column "B" to "AA", I have data such as dates, values, text etc.

In the "changes" sheets (sheet3), I would like to have a comment in column "A" that says if the trade is “New”, “Deleted/matured” or “Changed”. If one trade is changed, I would like to see which cells that are changed by showing before and after values.

My main concerns are errors in my code and performance, e.g. sometimes I will have more than 500 rows x 30 columns in the spreadsheets.

When I download data from my trade system to excel, I will sometimes have cells that have no content, and I would like my code to take this into account. I don't think my current code does this in a good way.

Any suggestions/feedback would be appreciated!

```
Sub CompData()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet
    Dim ws1LRow As Long, ws2LRow As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim ws1LCol As Long, ws2LCol As Long
    Dim Cell1 As Range, Cell2 As Range
    Dim SearchString As String
    Dim MatchFound As Boolean
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim NewDeal As String, MatDeal As String, ChangedDeal As String

    NewDeal = "New deal"
    MatDeal = "Matured/deleted deal"
    ChangedDeal = "Changed deal"


    Set ws1 = Sheets("sheet1")
    With ws1
        ws1LRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        ws1LCol = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End With

    Set ws2 = Sheets("sheet2")
    With ws2
        ws2LRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        ws2LCol = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End With

    Set ws3 = Sheets("sheet3")
    With ws3
        Cells.Clear
    End With

    n = 1

    For i = 1 To ws1LRow

        SearchString = ws1.Range("A" & i).Value

        Set Cell1 = ws2.Columns(1).Find(What:=SearchString, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)




        If Not Cell1 Is Nothing Then
            Set Cell2 = Cell1
            MatchFound = True

            For j = 1 To ws1LCol
                If ws1.Cells(i, j).Value <> ws2.Cells(Cell1.Row, j).Value Then
                    MatchFound = False
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next

            If MatchFound = False Then
                ws3.Cells(n, 2).Value = ws1.Cells(i, 1).Value
                ws3.Cells(n, j + 1).Value = ws1.Cells(i, j).Value
                ws3.Cells(n, ws2LCol + 2).Value = ws2.Cells(i, 1).Value
                ws3.Cells(n, ws2LCol + j + 1).Value = ws2.Cells(i, j).Value
                ws3.Cells(n, 1).Value = ChangedDeal
                n = n + 1
            End If

        Else:
            ws3.Cells(n, 2).Value = ws1.Cells(i, 1).Value
            ws3.Cells(n, 1).Value = NewDeal
            n = n + 1
        End If
    Next

    ws2.Select
    For i = 1 To ws2LRow
        SearchString = ws2.Range("A" & i).Value

        Set Cell2 = ws1.Columns(1).Find(What:=SearchString, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Cell2 Is Nothing Then
            ws3.Cells(n, 2).Value = ws2.Cells(i, 1).Value
            ws3.Cells(n, 1).Value = MatDeal
            n = n + 1
        End If
    Next

    ws3.Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is by building a sorted list of trade IDs with:

- 1st column: TRADE ID
- 2nd column: Row it was in the first list (#na if not)
- 3rd column: Row it was in the second list (#na if not)

This is done easily if you build each sorted list on each worksheet then aggregate the data in another function.

About your empty lines, I think you should do some preprocessing to aggregate the lines OR if you want to allow blank lines you need to decide the number of max rows in your spreadsheet.

PS: if you work for a certain French bank maybe pop at my floor and we can have a coffee :)